# MPMoviePlayerController streaming video not play Audio on iPad

Tags: ios, audio, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-streaming

This may be a silly question. But, don't know where the problem actually. I'm trying to stream my `http` streaming (HLS) through `MPMoviePlayercontroller` video streaming is fine. But, audio isn't working on real device (Working in Simulator) Here is my code,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mydomain:1935/coder/%@/playlist.m3u8", self.streamField.text]];
theMoviPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
theMoviPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
theMoviPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
theMoviPlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(theMoviPlayer.view.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2));
UIWindow *backgroundWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[theMoviPlayer.view setFrame:backgroundWindow.frame];
[backgroundWindow addSubview:theMoviPlayer.view];
[theMoviPlayer play];
```

Has anyone worked on this? I'm getting only with device for audio issue.

### Edit

I have tried below one,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];
MPMoviePlayerViewController  *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
```

This(URL only given to safari) works fine both iPad and Simulator iPad of Safari browser with Audio. But, not working as application on iPad except Simulator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First add  AVFoundation.framework and  add below code.

in .h file

```
 #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

and .m file

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

Comment: we need to add AvFoundation.framework for audio files.